# Comparing two arrays of objects and removing when two match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, frontend, javascript-objects

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I am using React and I have two arrays of objects:

- one for all possible booking times
- the other for existing bookings.

I am struggling to find a way of successfully looping over the `allSlots` array and removing any that have a matching time inside the `existingBookings` array.

In the example below, there are existing bookings at 10:00am, 10:40am, 11:00am and 11:20am.

The expected output would only leave 10:20am and 11:40am from the original array.

```
    const allSlots = [
    {
      date: "28 Sept 22",
      time: "10:00am"
    },
    {
      date: "28 Sept 22",
      time: "10:20am"
    },
    {
      date: "28 Sept 22",
      time: "10:40am"
    },
    {
      date: "28 Sept 22",
      time: "11:00am"
    },
    {
      date: "28 Sept 22",
      time: "11:20am"
    },
    {
      date: "28 Sept 22",
      time: "11:40am"
    }
  ];

    const existingBookings = [
    {
      time: "10:00am",
      propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
      userID: "Bq4b3uz129aE2D5TCbaOiLQJrvC2",
      date: "28 Sept 22"
    },
    {
      time: "11:00am",
      propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
      userID: "Ko2LdnQAdaE2OiLQJrvC2D5TCbA",
      date: "28 Sept 22"
    },
    {
      time: "10:40am",
      propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
      userID: "Ko2LdnQAdaE2OiLQJrvC2D5TCbA",
      date: "28 Sept 22"
    },
    {
      time: "11:20am",
      propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
      userID: "iLQJrKo2LdCbnQAdaE2OvC2D5TA",
      date: "28 Sept 22"
    }
  ];
```

I originally filtered the `existingBookings` data down to remove any that did not match the selected date with:

```
const existingBookings = allBookings.filter(
  (booking) => booking.date === selectedDate
);
```

However, I am struggling to manipulate things further. I really appreciate any insight and help you may be able to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as doing

```
freeSlots=allSlots.filter(s=>
 existingBookings.every(e=>e.time!=s.time||e.date!=s.date)
)
```

Here is a working (plain) JavaScript snippet:

```js
const allSlots = [
{
  date: "28 Sept 22",
  time: "10:00am"
},
{
  date: "28 Sept 22",
  time: "10:20am"
},
{
  date: "28 Sept 22",
  time: "10:40am"
},
{
  date: "28 Sept 22",
  time: "11:00am"
},
{
  date: "28 Sept 22",
  time: "11:20am"
},
{
  date: "28 Sept 22",
  time: "11:40am"
}
  ];

const existingBookings = [
{
  time: "10:00am",
  propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
  userID: "Bq4b3uz129aE2D5TCbaOiLQJrvC2",
  date: "28 Sept 22"
},
{
  time: "11:00am",
  propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
  userID: "Ko2LdnQAdaE2OiLQJrvC2D5TCbA",
  date: "28 Sept 22"
},
{
  time: "10:40am",
  propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
  userID: "Ko2LdnQAdaE2OiLQJrvC2D5TCbA",
  date: "28 Sept 22"
},
{
  time: "11:20am",
  propertyID: "XQPvl7MmLVNtxHdSRfDq",
  userID: "iLQJrKo2LdCbnQAdaE2OvC2D5TA",
  date: "28 Sept 22"
}
  ];

const freeSlots=allSlots.filter(s=>
 existingBookings.every(e=>e.time!=s.time||e.date!=s.date)
)

console.log(freeSlots);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to *filter* your `allSlots` array so that it only contains slots **not** present in `existingBookings`

```
const unusedSlots = allSlots.filter((slot) => {
  // See if the slot is booked
  const isBooked = existingBookings.some(
    (booking) => booking.time == slot.time && booking.date == slot.date
  )

  // Only keep free slots
  return !isBooked
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your approach but it is just returning undefined, i'm not sure why sorry

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
  const newAllSlots = allSlots.filter((slot)=>{
    const iSInExistingBookings = existingBookings.find(booking=>booking.time === slots.time && booking.date === slots.date)
    return !iSInExistingBookings
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what you already have booked with `existingBookings`, I would suggest looping through that first. Then you can recursively filter the `allSlots` array back into itself by checking if the date matches but the time does not. Once completed, the `allSlots` array should only have the date and times that haven't been booked.

```
existingBookings.forEach(booking => {        
    allSlots = allSlots.filter(slot => {
        return booking.date === slot.date && booking.time !== slot.time;
    });
});
```

Edit: You will have to scope `allSlots` with `let` instead of `const` for this to work. You could also assign `allSlots` to another variable if you want to keep `allSlots` in tact:

```
let slots = allSlots;
existingBookings.forEach(booking => {        
    slots = slots.filter(slot => {
        return booking.date === slot.date && booking.time !== slot.time;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your approach but it is just returning undefined, i'm not sure why sorry